# "dpkg was interrupted" when trying to install Java 9 after adding PPA

Tags: dpkg, java, ppa

I tried to install Java several times. but `dpkg` was interrupted. I do not know what it means.

[image: terminal screenshot, adding Oracle Java 9 PPA, successful]

[image: installing openjdk-9-jdk-headless fails, dpkg interrupted]

[image: terminal screenshot, adding Oracle Java 9 PPA, successful, but installing oracle-java9-installer fails]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

You might have got broken software. Without fixing this, installation is impossible.

To fix, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and do:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

as `dpkg` says...

Then proceed to installing Java by `apt`.